# Select rows from database then change a value in a column

Tags: mysql

I'm using the following query:

```
select id,link,size from files where status='-1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

then I want to change the 'status' column values of the selected rows to -2, is it possible to combine the 'select' and 'update' functions in the same query so that I don't have to query the database again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine Update and Select Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015621/combine-update-and-select-query)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to combine the select with an update:
try:

```
update files set status='-2' where status='-1' order by id desc limit 10;
```

The fields names are irrelevant here.

Comment: I want to select the values in those rows for further processing, and set the status value to -2 so that later I can select the next 10 rows. this query doesn't return the values I need.

Comment: I don't think you can have a select and update in one statement. Run a second select and you are done.

Comment: Works for me! Thanks!